# How to Prevent Perforce From Marking some Files As Read Only

Tags: perforce

I have created wpf .net framework project using vs 15 and added to perforce. After building the project bin and obj folder is created. Since the project code is uploaded to perforce the bin and obj folder becomes read only. How to Prevent Perforce From Marking Files/folders As Read Only from obj folder

Answer (score 1):

First: do you actually want these files to be added to Perforce?  Usually you would simply exclude generated files from source control, since they'll get rebuilt anyway and they may not be portable between environments.  The easy way to do this is via an exclusion in the client view and/or stream definition.

If you do want these files to be in Perforce but you want them to stay writable in the workspace (note that this means that changes to these files may not get uploaded on submit, since there will be no reminder to `p4 edit` them), use the `+w` filetype.  This can be applied:

- when you add the file, e.g. `p4 add -t +w bin/...`
- when you edit the file, e.g. `p4 edit -t +w bin/...`
- by setting the TypeMap ahead of time, e.g.:

```
p4 typemap

TypeMap:
    +w //.../bin/...
```

Comment: I have not added the files from the bin and obj folder to perforce. When i tried to build/rebuild  the project, bin and obj folder is marked as read only. I don't want these two folder to be read only mode. Is there a way, when the solution is build these two folder not to be in read only mode?

Comment: In your question you said: *Since the project code is uploaded to perforce the bin and obj folder becomes read only.*  If you're excluding these files from the depot, then they will not become read only, and there's no problem.

Comment: If the files aren't in Perforce, but they're becoming read only when you build, that's being done by your build system, not by Perforce.  I suspect the files **are** in Perforce because you added them by accident; I'd recommend deleting them from Perforce and then excluding them from your client view so you don't accidentally re-add them.